Theorem concerning Density and Duality in the Banach spaces $L^p(0,\infty)$: yielding $\Rightarrow f^* = \theta^*$
friends :-),
I am reading an old research paper from 1955, and I having problems understanding one part of it: Let

$X$ being one of the Banach spaces of $L^p(0, \infty)$ with $p \geq 1$, and
$S$ being the set of finite sums $\sum_{n=0}^{N}c_n e^{—\lambda_n x}$, with $(\lambda_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ being a sequence of distinct positive numbers.

Then, they claim that according to the "general theory" (without giving it a name) the following two statements are equivalent:
1.) $S$ is dense in $X$,
2.) $(f^*, s) = 0$, for every $s$ of $S$, implies $f^* = \theta^*$ ($\theta^*$ is the zero element of $X^*$).
Furthermore, they claim, that in the considered spaces, the scalar product ist defined as follows:
$(f^*, e^{-\lambda_n x}) := \int_{0}^{\infty} f^*(x) e^{-\lambda_n x}$.
I looked into more than ten books, why those two statements are equivalent, I guess, $f^*$ means a functional in the dual space $X^*$, and both statements relate to the orthogonality properties of the $L^p(0,\infty)$ spaces, and use somehow the dual space to define an orthogonality property.
However, most books I found where mostly concerned with Hilbert spaces and the Riesz representation theory and Hahn-Banach theorem for that, but I didn't find any theorem mentioning the 2nd statement exactly (the $\Rightarrow f^* = \theta^*$ part), so I am still confused, if this property is related to the "Best Approximation" property in $L^p$ spaces, if it is true for all Banach spaces or only $L^p$ ones.
Therefore, I would highly appreciate a hint, what to look for, i.e., what kind of theorems are exactly involved here or a book recommendation on it.
Have a nice & stressless pre-chrismas week! cheers.

This is true in any Banach space.

Thank you @EvangelopoulosFoivos for your comment and link!
I checked your link, but there is no book referenced, where I can read on that.
I myself was reading Conways "functional analysis", and in his Chapter "Banach Spaces", on p.84, I found something very similar, but he mentions "manifolds" in the theorem, were I didn't understand it. Maybe you can recommend me some book which is more easy to understand on that theorem? - thank you & good night

Some authors refer to linear (sub)spaces as manifolds. I am pretty sure you can also find it in Megginson's book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0603-3

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Thank you again, I will try to get that book from my library.
So what shall I do with this question? -- delete it or you want to give an answer so I can accept it, or just rest it like that?

As I said in the comments, this is true in any Banach space, i.e. a subspace $V\subset X$ is dense if and only if the only linear functional $x^* \in X^*$ that annihilates $V$, in the sense that $x^*\mid_V=0$,  is the zero functional. In other words, the annihilator of $V$
$$V^\bot := \{ x^* \in X^* \colon x^*\mid_V=0 \}$$
contains only the zero functional $V^\bot = \{0\}$.
One direction is trivial: If $V$ is dense and $x^*\mid_V=0$ then by continuity $x^*=0$. The opposite is due to Hahn-Banach for if $V$ is not dense then there exists a non-zero linear functional $x^* \in X^*$ (with norm one) such that $x^*\mid_{\overline V}=0$.
A similar result is true for subspaces of $X^*$, namely, a subspace $Z \subset X^*$ is weak-star dense if and only if $Z$ is total (a.k.a. separates the points of $X$) i.e. the only element $x$ that satisfies
$$ \langle x^*,x \rangle =0 , \quad \forall x^*\in Z $$
is the zero element $x=0$. This is equivalent to saying that the pre-annihilator
$${}^\bot Z := \{ x \in X \colon \langle x^*,x \rangle =0, \text{ for all } x^* \in Z\}$$
contains only the zero element ${}^\bot Z =0$. This also follows from Hahn-Banach but you need to use the strong separation theorem, see this answer.
Finally, there is a nice relation between annihilators and pre-annihilators, namely,
$$ {}^\bot (V^\bot) := \{x \in X \colon \langle x^*,x\rangle =0, \quad \text{ for all } x^* \in V^\bot\} = \overline{V} \subset X$$
and
$$ ({}^\bot Z)^\bot := \{ x^* \in X^* \colon  x^* \mid _{{}^\bot Z} =0 \} = \overline{Z}^{w^*} \subset X^* \quad (\text{weak-star closure})$$

Thank you @EvangelopoulosFoivos for your answer, and in particular for putting many related terms and theorems I read about, but didn't quite get, in a useful and better to understand way together!
